# IBOutlet UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I got 30 of these codes, with the same implementation:

// .h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UIImageView *circle;
IBOutlet UIImageView *circle2;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *circle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *circle2;
```

// .m

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize circle;
@synthesize circle2;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
circle = [[UIImageView alloc]
                      initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle.png"]];
circle2 = [[UIImageView alloc]
                      initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle.png"]];
}
```

And somewhere in my code, Im adding it as a subview.

My problem is,Is there a way to make it shorter, for it to be maintainable.

Comment: What do you mean by shorter and why are you using IBOutlet when you are creating UIImageView programatically ?

Comment: IBOutlet is only need when you need to make connection with XIB files , but as you are not creating these image view in XIB then no need to add IBOutlet here.

Comment: why do u have ivar's when u have properties? there is no need for them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one `IBOutletCollection` instead of 30 `IBOutlets`. You probably want to set the tag on each `UIImageView` though, so you can still tell them apart.

(This answer assumes you use a nib. Remove the lines where you instantiate the `UIImageView`s in `viewDidLoad` if so.)

Comment: It can be use even though Im using only one image?

Comment: If you want to show the same image 30 times, yes sure, nothing stopping you there. You can reuse `UIImage`s, but not `UIImageView`s.

Answer (score 0):

If you use name like - `Circle1.png`, `Circle2.png`, then you can go for for loop for creating this in a loop.

Something like -

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageCount ; i++ ) {
    circle = [[UIImageView alloc]
                  initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Circle%d.png" , i]]];
}
```

Comment: My image is only one. And I want to be able to use it again and again.

Comment: tell the exact scenario? you want same image 30 times?

Comment: yes. I want to put the same image in different positions/coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a pattern to where you are putting these views in their superview?  If so, you could use a for loop that goes to 30 and programmatically create the views and add them to their superview.

So for example:

```
   for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        UIImageView* circle = [[UIImageView alloc]
                      initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle.png"]];
        [self.view addSubview:circle];
    }
```

Would add 100 of the image views you would want.  Of course you will need to adjust the positions of each of these views in the loop, but this is the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

while creating this viewcontroller pass the frame as a parameter.thats the only thing changing rite??.the image is same and as there are no other properties .. it may work